# how to enable the neon glow in synthwave 84 on windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

it shows "You must run VS code with admin privileges in order to enable Neon Dreams.".It doesn't work even after running vs-code as administrator.

Comment: I am also getting same error even after running vs-code as an administrator.

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by the new version of VSCode, the extension normally change the workbench files of electron-browser but electron-browser was removed in the commit https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/f4f1b04d872a2b94d9a5105a1eefb81a213c07f2 and it has been replaced by electron-sandbox.

So you have 2 choices :

- You can go back to previous version of VSCode (1.69 June version) by downloading it here https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69 and then run VSCode as Administrator and enable neon dreams again

Or

- You can stay in 1.70 and modify manually the extension :

1. Go to "C:/Users/YourUsername/.vscode/extensions/robbowen.synthwave... or wherever your vscode extensions are stored
2. Go to src/ and open extension.js
3. You will have to replace all the "electron-browser" with "electron-sandbox" so

```
      const htmlFile =
        base +
        (isWin
          ? "\\electron-browser\\workbench\\workbench.html"
          : "/electron-browser/workbench/workbench.html");

      const templateFile =
        base +
        (isWin
          ? "\\electron-browser\\workbench\\neondreams.js"
          : "/electron-browser/workbench/neondreams.js");
```

on line 34 become

```
      const htmlFile =
        base +
        (isWin
          ? "\\electron-sandbox\\workbench\\workbench.html"
          : "/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html");

      const templateFile =
        base +
        (isWin
          ? "\\electron-sandbox\\workbench\\neondreams.js"
          : "/electron-sandbox/workbench/neondreams.js");
```

and same operation at line 149 on

```
  var htmlFile =
    base +
    (isWin
      ? "\\electron-browser\\workbench\\workbench.html"
      : "/electron-browser/workbench/workbench.html");
```

4. Save extension.js, close VSCode, open VSCode as Administrator and Enable Neon Dreams again.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Btw, this is a temporary fix, the extension will publish a fix soon as a pull request is ready to be merge here : https://github.com/robb0wen/synthwave-vscode/pull/264

Comment: yup i will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

Following the advise of [S.Mollet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9924124/s-mollet) to find and replace `electron-browser` with `electron-sandbox` worked; only difference I was on mac, but principal was same.

Find vs code extension files, mine were in `~/.vscode/exentions/robb...`

and then to run vs code with admin I ran `sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"`

and then in vs code press `⌘-p` and select enable dreams.

I was losing so much productivity while my font wasnt glowing, smh.